# Yocto for old kernel versions meta-intel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I want to generate a linux image with yocto with meta-intel layer.

I've seen that it is possible to change the kernel version, but if I have undertand correctly, this version depends on the BSP too so I'm not sure if it is possible to use yocto with meta-intel layer to generate a linux image with a very old kernel version. 2.3.X in my case.

Comment: Are you sure about kernel version? If so, it's even pre-2.4 era, so the answer is **definitely no**, you may not do anything with that antique kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You're right the kernel version depends on the BSP. The answers to your question aren't so easy and success will depend on how many problems do you meet on the way. From my experience, I can say that it'll be very complicated and required good knowledge of the development Yocto.

Comment: thanks. Maybe yocto is not the best option for me. Any alternative? I've tried with Buildroot but I will need to create a toolchain compatible with that kernel version. Linux From the scratch could be another option but I expect a hell of version problems to do that for an old kernel version

Comment: I don't see easy way at the moment :/